# Empty parsers tika python

Tags: python, apache-tika, tika-server

When I run a simple command to tika I get empty parsers.

```
    from tika import parser
    url = 'mygroovyurl'
    string_parsed = parser.from_buffer('Good evening, Dave', serverEndpoint=url)
    string_parsed
```

I get back

```
{'metadata': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'X-Parsed-By': 'org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser',
  'X-TIKA:embedded_depth': '0',
  'X-TIKA:parse_time_millis': '1'},
 'content': None,
 'status': 200}
```

Comment: What parsers do you have? Have you checked `tika.config.getParsers()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a network security setting encoding outgoing data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). The parsers are there (I checked), but this server works fine for calls outside the network.